# Git on ubuntu server: other users cannot push

Tags: git, ubuntu, permissions

I have setup a git server on an ubuntu server machine.
Everything seems to work OK, and I am able to pull/push from other machines via ssh.

What is the problem is when I try to add other users to the server.
I create their accounts and they are able to pull, but when they try to push they get a message:

```
error: remote unpack failed: unable to create temporary object directory
```

I read online that this usually has to do with disk space on the remonte machine, but it's not the case here.

I suspect something with permissions, but i cannot find anything!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to create your repository with:

- the [`core.sharedRepository`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresharedRepository) set to `group` (or `true`)
- a group which will be common to all your users.

You can see a full example in "[Git: Sharing a single git controlled folder among a group under Linux](https://fabianlee.org/2018/12/02/git-sharing-a-single-git-controlled-folder-among-a-group-under-linux/)".
You cal also [change the permissions of your existing repository](https://serverfault.com/a/27040/783) to make sure it is accessible by that one common group.